# How to import data from the 2nd sheet of an excel file, to SQL database

Tags: sql, excel, database, sql-server-2008, import-from-excel

I have an Excel file that has several sheets, I want to import the data from the 2nd sheet but only the first 2 columns. I use SQL Server Management Studio. How can I do this?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please show your latest non-working attempt at solving this problem. It is usually more instructive to see fixes to your code than to read someone else's solution. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the import data tool that comes with SQL Server Management Studio, in the wizard you will get to a section where you can map the sheet to a table. You can select the drop down by the sheet and select the second sheet and then map this to a table. Next you will click edit mappings on the bottom right and select only the two columns you would like.